# XAMPP Unknown Host in windows

Tags: xampp, localhost

I'm facing below issue while use XAMPP in windows. Same working if I connect with VPN.

## Unknown Host

***Description: Unable to locate the server named "d8.kali" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again.***

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc: hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   d8.kali
```

> C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra: httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal-8"
ServerName d8.kali
ErrorLog "logs/d8.kali-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/d8.kali-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit:**
I have this setup in my local system.

As per below comment, used IP. Even not working.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
#.#.#.#(IP)   d8.kali
```

Comment: The hosts file is only for working on the server itself, it does nothing fir access from a remote machine (regardless of VPN).

Comment: @Lucero: So do you have any idea why I face this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to launch d8.kali from a remote machine? If so, you need to add d8.kali in remote machine's hosts file and map the ip of server. When you ping d8.kali in CMD of remote machine it should return IP of server. For permanent solution you need to create DNS entry for d8.kali in your network (not in VPN).

Comment: @slash: this is my local setup.

Comment: put your ip address in hosts file instead of 127.0.0.1 and disable your proxy (no option should be checked in LAN settings) and give it a try.

Comment: @slash: `127.0.0.1  localhost #.#.#.#  d8.kali` - Used my IP still facing same issue :(

Comment: @slash: 504 (Unknown Host) - This error message displayed in console.